How to display images in Blender on a panel
I would like to know the script to display the image data in Blender on the panel. The only way I can think of at the moment is to convert the image once into an icon.
At first I tried to register the image image directly as an icon, but for some reason it didn't work. I had no choice but to save it in a temporary folder. I used bpy.app.tempdir, but there seem to be several ways.
How to get Blender's temp directory via the Python API?
I think you need to be careful when loading and saving.
Scripts are shown in the answer.

How to display an image image on a panel
import bpy
import os
from bpy.utils import previews

# Initialize custom preview collections
preview_collections = {}

def save_images_to_temp():
    """Save images loaded in Blender as temporary files"""
    temp_dir = bpy.app.tempdir
    img_paths = {}
    
    for img in bpy.data.images:
        if img.has_data:  # Only process if the image has data
            img_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, img.name)
            if img.file_format == 'PNG':
                img_path += ".png"
            elif img.file_format == 'JPEG':
                img_path += ".jpg"
            else:
                img_path += ".bmp"
            
            img.save_render(img_path)
            img_paths[img.name] = img_path

    return img_paths

def load_image_icons(img_paths):
    """Register images from temporary files as custom icons"""
    pcoll_ = preview_collections.get("main")
    
    if pcoll_:
        unload_image_icons()
        
    
    pcoll = previews.new()

    
    for name, path in img_paths.items():
        pcoll.load(name, path, 'IMAGE')
    
    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll

def unload_image_icons():
    """Unregister custom icons"""
    pcoll = preview_collections.pop("main", None)
    if pcoll:
        previews.remove(pcoll)

class IMAGE_OT_load_image_icons(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "image.load_image_icons"
    bl_label = "Load Image Icons"
    bl_description = "Load image icons from temporary files"

    def execute(self, context):
        img_paths = save_images_to_temp()
        load_image_icons(img_paths)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class IMAGE_PT_custom_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Image Icons"
    bl_idname = "IMAGE_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tools'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pcoll = preview_collections.get("main")

        if pcoll:
            layout.operator(IMAGE_OT_load_image_icons.bl_idname, text="Load Image Icons")
            for img in bpy.data.images:
                if img.name in pcoll:
                    row = layout.row()
                    my_icon = pcoll[img.name]
                    row.label(text=img.name, icon_value=my_icon.icon_id)
                    row.template_icon(icon_value=pcoll[img.name].icon_id, scale=10.0)
        else:
            layout.operator(IMAGE_OT_load_image_icons.bl_idname, text="Load Image Icons")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(IMAGE_OT_load_image_icons)
    bpy.utils.register_class(IMAGE_PT_custom_panel)

def unregister():
    unload_image_icons()
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(IMAGE_PT_custom_panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(IMAGE_OT_load_image_icons)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()



consideration
In practice, you may need to load images only for conditions. In that case, you would need to put the list in a custom scene property to manage loading and saving.
